# Mongo export records only if greater than certain number

Tags: mongodb

I would like to export records from Mongo DB only if the total number of records based on the query is greater than say, 100

```
Example: db.userInfo.find('some query here').count({$gt:100})
```

Can someone tell me if something like this is possible? Basically I do not want user information who hardly have any activity on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Your are guessing new syntax. No, it is not possible on the query level. Implement something within your application code.

Comment: Can I do it into 2 queries? Like first I get the list of all users and their activity count and then I decide to export the user I am interested in. Is this possible ?

Comment: Read my last sentence once again and think about what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get a null cursor back from  your query in the case where less than 100 elements are found. You could probably use map/reduce to do this. 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview
But it might be easier just to handle the fact that the count is <100 in your application code and to ignore that result.